# How to process datas received from POST (NodeJs/Sequelize/Express)

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, node.js, sequelize.js

I would like to register a user into a MySQL database with express and Sequelize.

[image: server folder]

First I should precise that my client (AngularJS) POST the data into my routes.js (req.body contain my datas) file there :

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var passport = require('passport');
var session = require('express-session');
module.exports = function (app) {
//BodyParser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
//Passport
app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat', resave: true, saveUninitialized: true }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions

app.post('/registered', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.end();
});
}
```

Next I created a model User for Sequelize :

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, Sequelize) {

var User = sequelize.define('user', {

    id: {
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },

    firstname: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        notEmpty: true
    },

    lastname: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        notEmpty: true
    },

    email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        validate: {
            isEmail: true
        }
    },

    password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },

    password_confirmation: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
});

return User;
}
```

Now, I would like to create a user into my database with sequelize so I got a passport.js file there :

```
var bCrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');


module.exports = function(passport, user) {


var User = user;

var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;


passport.use('local-registered', new LocalStrategy(

    {

        usernameField: 'email',

        passwordField: 'password',

        passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback

    },

    function(req, email, password, done) {

        var generateHash = function(password) {

            return bCrypt.hashSync(password, bCrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);

        };

        User.findOne({
            where: {
                email: email
            }
        }).then(function(user) {

            if (user)

            {

                return done(null, false, {
                    message: 'That email is already taken'
                });

            } else

            {

                var userPassword = generateHash(password);

                var data =

                    {
                        email: email,

                        password: userPassword,

                        firstname: req.body.firstname,

                        lastname: req.body.lastname

                    };
                User.create(data).then(function(newUser, created) {
                    if (!newUser) {
                        return done(null, false);
                    }
                    if (newUser) {
                        return done(null, newUser);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
));
}
```

Which hash the password and use a sequelize function user.create() etc..

Connection to the database is already done, my models are loaded correctly but I want to separate all files which are polluting my server.js file.

That's why I created a routes folder which contain all my routes with processing datas.

But my problem is that I don't know how to use my passport.js into my routes.js file.

Any idea please ?

Comment: route file should be like this.
const passport = require('passport');
const router = express.Router();
router.use(passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }));